# Question about the Division operator in R not returning the correct value

Tags: r

I am trying to caculate the Bayes Theorem for Cancer and tried to plug in the correct values in my formula as such:

```
cancer <- (1 * (1/100000)) / (1*(1/100000)) + ((10/99999) * (99999/100000))
```

In this case, cancer = 1.0001

However, the correct answer should be: 0.09090909, as proven by running the code separately, like this:

```
num = (1 * (1/100000))
den = (1*(1/100000)) + ((10/99999) * (99999/100000))

num / den

> 0.09090909
```

Can you please let me know why this is the case and how I should run the combined equation in the future to get the proper result?

Comment: You need to put parenthesis around your denominator: `cancer <- (1 * (1/100000)) / ((1*(1/100000)) + ((10/99999) * (99999/100000)))` This is a simple case of standard rules of order of operations with mathematical operators. This information is listed in the `?Syntax` help page. Note that `6 / 2 * 3` is different from `6 / (2 * 3)`

Comment: Ahhh... Okay; I understand now.  the divisor itself needs to be considered into the whole equation process.  Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses are needed:

```
cancer <- (1 * (1/100000)) / ((1*(1/100000)) + ((10/99999) * (99999/100000)))
```